# Add body.click() trigger from inside another element.click() only once

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

Sorry this is so long, I tried to condense it.

I am using jQuery to cycle through several elements and add click triggers to each of their parents. When the parent is clicked, the child element is made visible and moved outside the parent.

In this way, I have created a bottom fixed toolbar where the parent is a button and the child is the panel that is displayed or hidden when the button is clicked. Everything works great, except I can't figure out how to make it so when the user clicks outside the revealed panel, the panel toggles away.

Here is some sample markup:

```
<div class="dashbar">
   <div class="dash-button">
      Button One
      
      <div class="dash-panel">
          This is the panel that is toggled when button one is clicked
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Any number of other buttons -->
</div>
```

Again, when any dash-button is clicked it moves the child dash-panel outside its parent, and makes it visible (along with some other style trickery).

I have several types of panels (menus, modals, panels, etc) all stored in an object. The jQuery I use to cycle through the elements and add the click triggers is:

```
$.each(['panel', 'menu', 'etc'], function (index, value) {
    // Select all the elements that match this panel type
    var panelClass = '.dash-' + value;
    var $panels = $(panelClass);

    // Now cycle through those elements
    $panels.each(function () {

        // Select the panel to be displayed and its parent
        var $panel = $(this);
        var $parent = $panel.parent();

        // Add the click event to the parent
        $parent.click(function () {
            // Toggle the panel with dashbar.panels.toggle($panel) elsewhere in my object
        });
    });
});
```

All that works splendidly. I have tried adding:

```
$( "body").one('click', function() {
     // conceal the panel with dashbar.panels.conceal($panel);
});

$parent.click(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
});

$panel.click(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

outside `$parent.click()`, but then the event runs an absurd amount of times and is buggy.

What I really want is to add the event WHEN the parent is clicked, and remove it after it hides the menu. But, when I add the above INSIDE `$parent.click()` I have to click the parent twice the first time in order to reveal the panel. I can only assume that the `body.click()` action is taking effect the first time and hiding the panel.

I'm stumped and would love to know anything that will get my desired result. Happy to rewrite my code.

Comment: Hint at the edge: `$( "body").one('click', function()` the `.one`should be `.on` !

Comment: Thanks! I thought .one removes the action after it has been clicked. When the trigger is inside the $parent.click() I want it to be removed after the its use and readded on the next $parent.click(). Maybe, anyway.

Comment: have you tried using .unbind? like this $( "body").unbind().on('click', function() { I haven't tried it in your case, but it has worked for me in the past.